# PHP add character to the end of every new word

Tags: php

I have a string of words separated by spaces (except the last word) and I would like to know if there is a way to add a character to the end of each new word. For example:

```
$string = "this is a short string of words"
```

would become

```
$string = "this; is; a; short; string; of; words;"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'lorem ipsum';  
$str_modified = str_replace(' ','; ',trim($str)).';';
```

Answer (score 3):

[Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode("; ", explode(" ", $string)).";";
```

Comment: Wrap it in a trim to get rid of the trailing space.

Comment: It does need a `;` but not a `trim`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace()` like this:

```
$string = "this is a short string of words";
echo preg_replace('~(\w+)~', '$1;',$string);

// output: this; is; a; short; string; of; words;
```

Comment: Just for the record, Explode and Implode will be far much faster :)

Comment: @KerePuki No I were the last :).. Also I must admit that `str_replace()` is faster. I would give JLP the accept. He was the fastest with the best answer

Comment: True. Roughly the same time with Explode and Implode but he did answer first.

Comment: he answered three minutes before me ;)